# jq: iterate over regex matches in a string

Tags: iteration, jq

I'm reworking some json using `jq` and trying to extract some strings from a larger description and move them into an array of related controls.

Here's my input json:

```json
{"description": "Fail-safe procedures include, for example, alerting operator personnel and providing specific instructions on subsequent steps to take (e.g., do nothing, re-establish system settings, shut down processes, restart the system, or contact designated organizational personnel). Related controls: CA-2, CA-7, CM-3, CM-5, CM-8, MA-2, IR-4, RA-5, SA-10, SA-1x, SI-1x"}
```

The output I want is:

```json
{"description": "Fail-safe procedures include, for example, alerting operator personnel and providing specific instructions on subsequent steps to take (e.g., do nothing, re-establish system settings, shut down processes, restart the system, or contact designated organizational personnel).",
"relatedControls": ["CA-2", "CA-7", "CM-3", "CM-5", "CM-8", "MA-2", "IR-4", "RA-5", "SA-10", "SA-1x", "SI-1x"}
```

I've worked out something I think is pretty close, but this is creating more objects instead of creating an array of controls like I wanted.

```bash
jq '. | {description: .description | sub(" Related controls:.*";""), relatedControls: .description | scan("[A-Z]{2}-\\d[0-9x]?") }'
```

Here's the whole thing on one line so it's easy to test:

```
echo '{"description": "Fail-safe procedures include, for example, alerting operator personnel and providing specific instructions on subsequent steps to take (e.g., do nothing, re-establish system settings, shut down processes, restart the system, or contact designated organizational personnel). Related controls: CA-2, CA-7, CM-3, CM-5, CM-8, MA-2, IR-4, RA-5, SA-10, SA-1x, SI-1x"}' | jq '. | {description: .description | sub(" Related controls:.*";""), relatedControls: .description | scan("[A-Z]{2}-\\d[0-9x]?") }'
```

`jq` wizards... what a I missing to get the output I'm after?

Comment: Change `scan(…)` to `[scan(…)]` in order to collect the items into an array (rather than letting them multiply out the overall result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just split `/` at `" Related controls: "`, then split again at `", "`:

```bash
.description / " Related controls: "
| {description: .[0], relatedControls: (.[1] / ", ")}
```

Alternatively, here's another approach using `capture` and `scan` with your regular expressions:

```bash
.description
| capture("(?<description>.*) Related controls: (?<relatedControls>.*)")
| .relatedControls |= [scan("[A-Z]{2}-\\d[0-9x]?")]
```

Output:

```json
{
  "description": "Fail-safe procedures include, for example, alerting operator personnel and providing specific instructions on subsequent steps to take (e.g., do nothing, re-establish system settings, shut down processes, restart the system, or contact designated organizational personnel).",
  "relatedControls": [
    "CA-2",
    "CA-7",
    "CM-3",
    "CM-5",
    "CM-8",
    "MA-2",
    "IR-4",
    "RA-5",
    "SA-10",
    "SA-1x",
    "SI-1x"
  ]
}
```